# How to replace a string in javascript

Tags: string, double-quotes

Here is my data

data = "67.45"

want to remove the double quotes and wanted my out to be as
data = 67.45

What is the best way to achieve
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = "67.45"

console.log(parseFloat(data))
```

data is having string value. if you want to convert string to float.

you just need to use parseFloat.

var data = "67.45"

parseFloat(data)

you will get float value

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var ret = data.replace('"','');
console.log(ret);   //should show your string with out quotes
```

or you can use this:

```
data.replace(/"/g,'');
```